# Validate string format

Tags: javascript, string, validation

I had a list of different formats for the string. When a string produces a string of something, the users must key-in the format of that particular string.

If the given string are

> A-01-13A
>
> (One alphabet, follow by dash, two numbers, follow by dash, two numbers, and one alphabet)

or

> A-01-13
>
> (One alphabet, follow by dash, two numbers, follow by dash, two numbers)

---

The user's key-in string is **validated** below:

> B-13-99
>
> B-14-11A

The user's key-in string is **NOT validated** below:

> B-13-100

---

What is the best way to validate the given string using Regex or other methods in Javascript?

Comment: Have you tried any regex?

Comment: Nope. I'm new to regex.

Comment: @AbelChun: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use simple regex:

```
const userKeyRegExp = /^[A-Z]\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2}[A-Z]?$/;

const valid = userKeyRegExp.test('A-01-13A');

console.log(valid);
```

Comment: When using a regular expression to validate a string, *test* is more semantic as it returns true or false.

Answer (score 5):

The RegExp expression you are looking for is:

```
^([a-zA-Z]{1}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z]{0,1})$
```

This means:
Starts with one character, followed by a dash, followed by two numbers, followed by a dash, followed by two numbers, ends with one or none characters.

You can play with it in [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/QVzOBB/2) or you can leverage in Javascript as follows:

```js
/** @const {!RegExp} Code pattern to validate. */
const CODE_PATTERN = /^([a-zA-Z]{1}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z]{0,1})$/;


/**
 * Validate that a certain code matches expected RegExp.
 * Uses CODE_PATTERN to validate.
 * @param {string} code - Code to be validated.
 * @return {bool} Whether provided code matches pattern.
 */
const validateCode = function(code) {
  return CODE_PATTERN.test(code);
};



// Test sample of codes.
const testCodes = [
  'A-01-13A',
  'A-01-13',
  'B-13-99',
  'B-14-11A',
  'B-13-100'
];
for (code of testCodes) {
  const isValidCode = validateCode(code);
  console.log(isValidCode);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in the following way

```js
function validate(str){
    return str.match(/^[A-Z]-\d{2}-\d{2}[A-Z]?$/) !== null;
}


console.log(validate('A-01-13A'));
console.log(validate('A-01-13'));
console.log(validate('B-13-99'));
console.log(validate('B-14-11A'));
console.log(validate('B-13-100'));
```